# Calculate probability of minimum number of sample types within a sample distribution - z-statistics vs. binomial distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution, z-statistic

(The title may have to be changed, because I am learning statistics and can't describe problems through the use of the correct terminologies yet)

I have the following question:

"90% of all plant species are classified angiosperms. If you were randomly selecting 200 plants from all known plants species, what is the probability to have at least 95% of angiosperms in my sample?"

In the statistical analysis course I am following, the teacher is calculating this probability through a z-statistic, with SE = sqrt((p-(1-p)/n)). The z-statistic is calculated as:

```
z-statistic = (0.95 - 0.90) / SE =  2.36
p_value = 0.0091
```

I was wondering whether we could calculate the same probability through the binomial distribution, where:

```
n = 200
at_least = 200*95% = 190
p = 0.9
1-p = 0.1

p_value = for k=at_least->n sum{ n!/(at_least! * (n-at_least)!) * p**(at_least) * (1-p)**(n-at_least) } 
= 0.0081
```

because I get two different probabilities, which are however close to each other.
In my head, both methods should achieve the same purpose. What am I doing wrong? Or is this maybe due to an approximation to the normal distribution for the z-statistic?

Comment: See [Approximating Binomial Distribution with Normal vs Poisson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199067/approximating-binomial-distribution-with-normal-vs-poisson)

Comment: Yes, the use of a Z statistic is an approximation; and this case--because it involves relatively extreme quantiles of a highly skewed Binomial distribution and a not very large sample--is one where it would generally be inadvisable to use that approximation.  Consider this just a simple exercise in how to use the Normal approximation rather than anything deeper or more meaningful than that.